# UITableview doesn't call cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The first time the view controller is pushed (from the previous view controller) all the delegate methods are called (inside a navigation controller).

When pressing back to return to the previous view controller , and then pushing it again (for the second time)

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't called but `numberOfRowsInSection` and numberOfSectionsInTableView are called.

The `reloadData` is called within

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and I have tried in

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and it doesn't help.

Edit

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1; // called
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3; // called
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // relevant code for cell - THIS METHOD IS NOT CALLED SECOND TIME
}
```

Comment: Can you give the code for cellForRowIndexPath in here?

Comment: check your data source. if the number of rows is 0 then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not get called

Comment: How/where is the datasource property set? cellForRowAtIndexPath: is a datasource method not a delegate one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find any valid reason as explained above I will highlight
another mistake one can make is (as I once did).

The steps to note are

1) initialise your custom table view as first step 
2) set the delegate and datasource before you add the tableView to you view.

If one has done these steps mistakenly after adding to the tableview to your self.view object, then it would be a silent way to make yourself struggle.Correct order is as under:

```
self.myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,    myViewwidth, 120) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.myTableView.tag = MY_TABLEVIEW_TAG;
self.myTableView.delegate = self;
self.myTableView.dataSource = self; 
[self.view addSubview:self.myTableView];
```

Answer (score 0):

This always happens when you define your underlying data source (array or Dictionary) as `weak`, the first time it gets pushed, the data is there, when deallocated, it will release and you lose control over it.

Double check the weak/strong condition and optionally set the data source before pushing again.

Comment: number of rows and section is hard coded. They are called. Row for indexpath isn't

Comment: are you sure the `reloadData` is happening? have you tried putting breakpoints on those view delegates (willappear or didappear)

Comment: and one more thing, I'm not sure, but because of the way table view caches table cells, if the number of rows doesn't change upon reloads, this method might not even get called... I need to investigate it more.

Comment: Sections is called - it is returning 3, then rows is called - it returns 1, then Row for index path is NOT called.

Comment: in the added codes, upon view delegates you forgot to call `super`'s delegates as well. e.g. `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{[super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem here. I'm not sure how you're pushing the table view. please add the code related to pushing your table to view as well.

Comment: I wish you could post some codes on how you're pushing the view containing your tableview as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have set/connected Delegate and Datasource to the File's Owner.

And check the array count of your model, if it contains value of not?

NSLog in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method and check it by using breakpoints and step over.